# How to resolve \\.\xxx path to usb device with the actual device path

Tags: c, winapi, path, device, createfile

I have a usb device that I use CreateFile to open.

```
hDev = CreateFile("\\\\.\\jyezu-0",...);   // 0..32 for the dev number
hDev2 = CreateFile("\\\\.\\jyezu-1",....); // etc...
```

This is in legacy code and has worked properly for some time.

Now I am working with the SetupAPI and would like to link the device info enumerated by the SetupAPI with the above paths

i.e. - \.\jyezu-0 --> USB\VID_04B4&PID_8613\6&11D0BADA&0&2
       \.\jyezu-1 --> USB\VID_04B4&PID_8613\6&11D0BADA&0&3

The hardware is generic (no serial numbers yet, as application is for production and assigns the serial numbers later.

I need to track the PHYSICAL device through firmware and product ID changes and the only way I can figure how to do this is through the LocationInformation field ( Port#_XXXX.Hub#_XXXX)

I can't find much information on how the "\.\jyezu-0" path works for this device.  I want to avoid changing the startup code to use SetupAPI paths and only want to "link" on path to the other so I know, that after reprogram, restart, I'm still talking to the same physical device (by checking the Port/Hub info)

Any info on the origin / configuration of the \.\ paths to the USB\ paths would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not include a signoff or "Thanks" in a question.

Comment: Not exactly what you are searching for: Using `QueryDosDevice(NULL,...)` you get a list of all devices and using `QueryDosDevice("jyezu-0",...)` you get the unique system-internal device name. Many USB devices have two or more names (like `jyezu-0` and `HID#VID_04B4&PID_8613&MI_06&...`). You may search for a second device name belonging to the same system-internal device as `jyezu-0` that has the `HID#...` or `USB#...` format.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is helpful.  I'll play around with it to verify it can give me the details I need.

Comment: @MartinRosenau - tried what you suggested, but it only returns \Device\jyezu-0 when I call QueryDosDevice("jyezu-0",...).  I need to somehow link to the path used / returned by the SetupAPI  (USB\VID_0C9B&PID_0011\CAMERA_SN:___312)

Comment: `CM_Get_Device_ID_ListW(L"USB\\VID_0C9B&PID_0011", .., CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_PRESENT|CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_ENUMERATOR )` -> `CM_Locate_DevNodeW` -> `CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW(.. &DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName, )` -> `NtOpenFile`